# How to fix 'package org.springframework.jdbc.core does not exist'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

java: package org.springframework.jdbc.core does not exist
try to run and want to get resulted data when we run jdbc template it shows error of version I think I need to download but how please show me the process. Hope this much description is enough.

Comment: Corrected your title to what the error message actually says. Don't paraphrase error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot, as your tagging suggests, then add a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc`, which will pull in the necessary dependencies.

If you use Gradle, add to the `dependencies` section:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
```

If you use Maven, add to the `dependencies` tag:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc<artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you use "normal" Spring Framework (without Spring Boot), see the [answer by Codemaker2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734880/466862).